# Retrieve JSON Object Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm trying to get a JSON String from a URL but I keep getting a "NetworkOnMainThreadException". I thought I moved my network code to another thread but obviously not.

Here is the error:[image: error]

JSONParser

```
package com.example.jsonparsing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // json is UTF-8 by default i beleive
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result = sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.jsonparsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        RetrieveJSONString retrieveJSON = new RetrieveJSONString();
        retrieveJSON.run();
        String whatever = retrieveJSON.getJSONString();
    }
}

class RetrieveJSONString implements Runnable{

    JSONParser jParser;
    String jsonString;

    public void run() {
         // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String jsonString = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");

    }

    public String getJSONString(){

        return jsonString;
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jsonparsing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If anybody can shed some light on the problem I would appreciate it!

Comment: Can you post the error stack? And your Android Manifest file.

Comment: Updated with Error & Manifest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to do HTTP calls on the UI-thread, and you should never do that :) Use an AsyncTask instead. Here is a simple example:

```
GetJsonAsync getJson = new GetJsonAsync();
getJson.execute();

private class GetJsonAsync extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Do stuff before the operation
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            getJSONFromUrl();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Do stuff after the operation
        }
    }
```

Comment: btw this class needs to be in you Activity, so you will haveto instansiate your JSONparser there and call getJSONFromURL from it. Making a Runnable does not run it on a seperate thread unless you assign it to a Thread.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Android SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

Essentially, you want to do some sort of a threaded application, or else the GUI can get stuck. Look into AsyncTask or just threading for your JSON parsing needs.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `start()` on a `Thread` and not call the `run` method directly. You are calling the `retrieveJSON.run();` which will be run on the UI thread.

```
 new Thread(new RetrieveJSONString()).start();
```

---

I suggest using a `AsyncTask` for this purpose instead of a Thread, as you want to update the UI after fetching JSON. In AsyncTask, when the background job is done the `onPOstExecute()` method gets called, where you can update the UI.

Comment: Trying this now but, "The method start() is undefined for the type RetrieveJSONString"

Comment: Use this: `RetrieveJSONString retrieveJSON = new RetrieveJSONString(); new Thread(retrieveJSON).start();`

Answer (score 0):

Call `getJSONFromUrl` method inside `AscyTask` .this exception occur when process take long time. Call this `AscyTask` task by using this line

> new AppTask().execute();

```
public class AppTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){}  protected void onPreExecute(){ }

   protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
       getJSONFromUrl();
       return null;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) { }
}
```

Comment: It's not becuase it's taking to long time. See my answer. Also your code does not work :)